# Any ideas on designing a wide webpage

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to display nearly 16 input boxes in one row and open it in a  modal without getting a horizontal scrollbar. Is there a way to do design this effectively? I am getting a scrollbar since it si too big. Users will be using barcode scanner and scan items, putting all 16 inputboxes with length=12 (is necessary) is making the modal get a scroll bar which users don't want. Any suggestions? Using HTML5, jquery, css

```
<table id="setOpProd">
            <tr class="centerAlign">
                <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="ui-state-disabled" type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" /></td>
                <td><input class="ui-state-disabled" type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" /></td>
                <td><input class="ui-state-disabled" type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" /></td>
                <td><input class="ui-state-disabled" type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" /></td>
                <td><input class="ui-state-disabled" type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" /></td>
                <td><input class="ui-state-disabled" type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" /></td>
                <td><input class="ui-state-disabled" type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" /></td>
                <td><input class="ui-state-disabled" type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" /></td>
                <td><input class="active" type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" /></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Send us some example code or a graphic showing what you need to do.

Comment: Please provide a reason for downgrading the question, whoever downgraded it.

Comment: why do they have to be in a row? what's the reason for that constraint?

Answer (score 0):

There's really not a black-and-white way of making this work better. One option is to change to a grid that wraps

```
 1          2          3
_______    _______    _______
 4          5          6
_______    _______    _______
 7          8          9
_______    _______    _______
10          11         12
_______    _______    _______
```

Alternatively, come up with a different UI other than a scrollbar. Maybe an area with a large arrow that scrolls either on hover, or clicking. Throw in some keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl-Left, Ctrl-Right). It might be a little more usable than a scrollbar in some cases. This will require some Javascript.